# Как понять, что процесс майнинга происходит правильно?

Tags: криптовалюта, майнинг

Что я должен увидеть в консоли, чтобы понять, что майнинг идет правильным руслом и хоть какая-та копейка с этого есть? Например в том же XMRig и T-Rex?

Answer (score 0):

Примерно такой должен быть лог, если используется CPU и CUDA(GPU nVidia)

```
 * ABOUT        XMRig/6.20.0 gcc/11.2.0
 * LIBS         libuv/1.44.2 OpenSSL/1.1.1s hwloc/2.9.0
 * HUGE PAGES   permission granted
 * 1GB PAGES    unavailable
 * CPU          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v3 @ 2.30GHz (1) 64-bit AES VM
                L2:3.0 MB L3:30.0 MB 12C/24T NUMA:1
 * MEMORY       7.3/19.8 GB (37%)
                DIMM_A1: 4 GB DDR4 @ 2133 MHz 9905678-024.A00G    
                DIMM_B1: 16 GB DDR4 @ 2133 MHz CT16G4DFD824A.C16FN 
                NO DIMM: <empty>
                NO DIMM: <empty>
 * MOTHERBOARD  Default string - Default string
 * DONATE       1%
 * ASSEMBLY     auto:intel
 * POOL #1      xmrpool.eu:9999 algo auto
 * COMMANDS     hashrate, pause, resume, results, connection
 * OPENCL       disabled
 * CUDA         11.4/11.4/6.17.0
 * NVML         11.474.64/474.64 press e for health report
 * CUDA GPU     #0 03:00.0 NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650 Ti 0/0 MHz smx:4 arch:30 mem:1685/2048 MB
[2023-11-12 15:34:11.426]  net      use pool xmrpool.eu:9999 TLSv1.2 51.89.217.80
[2023-11-12 15:34:11.428]  net      fingerprint (SHA-256): "719f838fa8ae7844b7f25917c91d32185c594c4d36a3ed5bab233a433ecf9910"
[2023-11-12 15:34:11.429]  net      new job from xmrpool.eu:9999 diff 500054 algo rx/0 height 3016497 (9 tx)
[2023-11-12 15:34:11.430]  cpu      use argon2 implementation AVX2
[2023-11-12 15:34:11.965]  msr      register values for "intel" preset have been set successfully (536 ms)
[2023-11-12 15:34:11.966]  randomx  init dataset algo rx/0 (24 threads) seed ba6c1d8673e0a671...
[2023-11-12 15:34:11.967]  randomx  allocated 2336 MB (2080+256) huge pages 100% 1168/1168 +JIT (0 ms)
[2023-11-12 15:34:15.414]  randomx  dataset ready (3446 ms)
[2023-11-12 15:34:15.414]  cpu      use profile  rx  (22 threads) scratchpad 2048 KB
[2023-11-12 15:34:15.417]  nvidia   use profile  rx  (1 thread) scratchpad 2048 KB
|  # | GPU |  BUS ID | INTENSITY | THREADS | BLOCKS | BF |  BS | MEMORY | NAME
|  0 |   0 | 03:00.0 |       256 |      32 |      8 |  8 |  25 |    512 | NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650 Ti
[2023-11-12 15:34:15.485]  cpu      READY threads 22/22 (22) huge pages 100% 22/22 memory 45056 KB (71 ms)
[2023-11-12 15:34:15.605]  nvidia   READY threads 1/1 (186 ms)
[2023-11-12 15:34:45.934]  net      new job from xmrpool.eu:9999 diff 500054 algo rx/0 height 3016497 (15 tx)
[2023-11-12 15:34:51.675]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1475.8 n/a n/a H/s max 1496.0 H/s
[2023-11-12 15:35:16.706]  nvidia   #0 03:00.0   0W  0C
[2023-11-12 15:35:16.707]  miner    speed 10s/60s/15m 1494.2 1485.9 n/a H/s max 1496.2 H/s
[2023-11-12 15:37:09.435]  net      new job from xmrpool.eu:9999 diff 500054 algo rx/0 height 3016500 (5 tx)
[2023-11-12 15:39:48.052]  cpu      accepted (1/0) diff 500054 (109 ms)
[2023-11-12 15:39:51.439]  signal   SIGHUP received, exiting
[2023-11-12 15:39:51.462]  cpu      stopped (18 ms)
[2023-11-12 15:39:51.473]  nvidia   stopped (10 ms)
```